# Rspec tags and filters - Multiple values for a filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a test suite that runs across several versions of a software application. I'd like to be able to tag those tests that vary based on different versions so that the filters I have set up only run the tests for this particular version.

I'm looking for something like:

```
describe "the magic page", :version=>["all-magic", "some_magic"]
   it "exists!"
end

describe "the magic page", :version=>["no-magic"]
   it "does not exist!"
end

Rspec.configure do |config|
  this_version= some_version_parameter_passed_in || "no_magic"
  config.filter_run :version includes this_version
end
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, but it should give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this with Rspec. Take a look at the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option), and try something like this:

```
describe "the magic page", :all-magic => true, :some-magic => true
   it "exists!"
end

describe "the magic page", :no-magic => true
   it "does not exist!"
end
```

Then to run the tests with the magic tag you can use the command:

```
rspec --tag magic
```

Or you can edit your `.rspec`:

```
--tag magic
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Okay, this technically answers the question, so you get it. But it mostly served to illustrate the question wasn't good enough to solve my problem. ;) I'll make a new, slightly more expansive question, but thanks for the starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambdas in your filter like this:

```
config.filter_run_including :foo => lambda {|v| v == 'bar'}
```

So you could do something like

```
config.filter_run_including :version => lambda {|v| v.include? current_version}
```

Or to only run tests with the correct :versions (I think this is what you're looking for),

```
config.filter_run_excluding :version => lambda {|v| !v.include? current_version}
```

Comment: works for me when i want to run case by one key multiple value, thanks